# Why Google Play Services Versions are different?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I need to know **Google Play Services Version** on some devices.

After googling and searching stackoverflow, I found following two ways and tried these.

A. use PackageInfo

```
getPackageManager()
    .getPackageInfo(GoogleApiAvailability.GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_PACKAGE, 0 )
    .versionCode;
```

B. use GoogleApiAvailability directly.

```
GoogleApiAvailability.GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION_CODE;
```

I got results but results are different value.

result:

```
A: 12673023
B: 11717000
```

On the device, Settings -> Apps & Notification -> Google Play Services,  version 
 shows 12.6.73.

It seems **A** is correct.

On the other hand, **B** is simple and latest way.

Why is this two are different? which one is correct value? Everyone knows?

Comment: GoogleApiAvailability.GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION_CODE is the minimum required by your app, not the version installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GoogleApiAvailability.GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION_CODE` is the minimum required by your app, not the version installed

Comment: thanks. It's clear. API document says `Google Play services client library version (declared in library's AndroidManifest.xml android:versionCode).`.
 It means this value from linked library version. I wrote `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'` in dependency. I should use **A**.